# CakePHP Form Helper and Datetime

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, form-helpers

I have used the form helper to create a date time selection and when I access the `$this->data`.

It looks like the following.

```
[Timetable] => Array
    (
        [event_id] => 133
        [location_id] => 39
        [start] => Array
            (
                [hour] => 09
                [min] => 06
                [day] => 11
                [month] => 03
                [year] => 2011
            )

    )
```

But I want this to look more like this...

```
[Timetable] => Array
    (
        [event_id] => 133
        [location_id] => 39
        [start] => 2011-03-11 09:06:00

    )
```

Is there a way to transform it to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just rebuild the `$this->data['Timetable']['start']` var in your controller like so:

```
$this->data['Timetable']['start'] = $this->data['Timetable']['start']['year']
    .'-'.$this->data['Timetable']['start']['month']
    .'-'.$this->data['Timetable']['start']['day']
    .' '.$this->data['Timetable']['start']['hour']
    .':'.$this->data['Timetable']['start']['min'];
```

Should work fine.

Comment: sprintf() would be nicer :) but this is not needed as cake knows what to do with it.

Comment: Would this be the best way to do it then? Can it not be done using the form helper itself?

Comment: Not really as the helper is only available by design in the view.

Comment: I would probably put this in the `Timetable` model's `beforeSave()` function than in the controller. Just sayin'

Answer (score 1):

This is undocumented in the Cookbook, but the function the model uses to convert that array into a database-friendly format is [`Model::deconstruct($field, $data)`](http://api.cakephp.org/view_source/model/#l-849). You can use it as follows:

```
$startAsString = $this->Timetable->deconstruct(
    'start', $this->data['Timetable']['start']
);
```

This solution has the benefit of not breaking the MVC abstraction by having your controller know anything about the structure of data submitted by a form or how the database stores it.

Comment: You can access it from within your model, or from your controller. It depends on where you need access to the datetime, and for what purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the form helper to generate your code, you can't get it into a single index unless you change your form helper.

You're probably using

```
$this->Form->input('start')
```

Changing it to the below will make it come out the way you want.

```
$this->Form->input('start', array('type'=>'text'));
```

However, if you do this, you'll lose out on all the dropdowns that cake auto generates for you. Not a problem if you use a datepicker.

Comment: cake will know what to do with the array and save it as it is.

Comment: @dogmatic69, yup that is true. I'm assuming the OP wants it as a single string for something else.